# How can I delete objectClass from LDAP object along with its attributes?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

Is there a way to delete an objectClass from some object along with all its attributes with Java code? When I try:

```
context..modifyAttributes(rdn, new ModificationItem[]{new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("objectClass", objectClassName))})
```

I recieve LDAP error, caused by some attributes from that objec class which are still there. I don't want to remove all the attributes before, because I cannot be sure which one of them is assigned to the object at runtime (fetching the object to know that is bad for my performance). Is there some nice way to do that from the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the attributes you want to delete to the `ModificationItem[]` array.

Comment: The problem is I cannot tell which attributes of that objectClass are present at object at given time. If I put them all, then I recieve error for every attribute which is not assigned to that object in LDAP during modification.